# Cast AnyPublisher to Publisher in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I am using a `Publisher<Int,Never>` in combine, and I am trying to return a `Published<Int>.Publisher`

It is possible in combine to transform an `AnyPublisher<Int,Never>` into a `Published<Int>.Publisher` ?

Comment: How about making that function return a `AnyPublisher<Int,Never>` instead? This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not possible. `AnyPublisher` is a type erased version of `Publisher`. Once you type erase a variable, the original type information is lost (or at the very least hidden) for the lifetime of the object, you cannot convert it back to the original type.

If you need to return a `Published<Int>.Publisher`, simply make that the return type of your function. `Published<Int>.Publisher` is a struct, so you can use it as a return type (unlike `Publisher`, which is a protocol with associated types).